# Is is good practice to add a dummy method into a superclass so the subclass can override it?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism, overriding

I have a problem. It stems from calling a subclass method from a superclass, but with a twist. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

For example let's say I have a subclass `MultipleChoice` that extends an abstract superclass `Question`. The class `MultipleChoice` has a method `addChoice(String choice)`, while `Question` does everything any question should do, like display the question prompt, and check for the correct answer.

I'd like to create an instance of `MultipleChoice` that references `Question`, and then call the `addChoice(String choice)` method. The reason for this is because I'd like to create a list of questions, and then put different types of questions in there (e.g. multiple choice, true and false, etc.).

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new MultipleChoice()); //this is valid
list.get(0).addChoice("abc");
list.get(0).addChoice("xyz"); //etc
```

However, this of course is a compile error, since not every question is a multiple choice type of question.

I know of two solutions for this.

1. Typecast: `((MultipleChoice)list.get(0)).addChoice("abc");`
2. Add the method `addChoice(String choice)` into the superclass `Question`, so it can be overridden by `MultiplceChoice`.

Since I'm going to be accessing `list` many times, option 1 is well... ugly, while option 2 just seems to really poor practice, especially since `Question` is abstract.

How can I approach this elegantly?

Comment: This can be answered and solved in multiple ways. Can you perhaps add more background and maybe post the Question superclass and maybe other subclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good practice to add a dummy method to the superclass that will only be used by one subclass. This will lead to confusion and misunderstanding if someone else (or you in the future) will work on the code and add a new type of question that will inherit from your superclass `Question`.

You can add objects to your list like so:

```
ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();

MultipleChoice multipleChoiceQ1 = new MultipleChoice();
multipleChoiceQ1.addChoice("abc");

MultipleChoice multipleChoiceQ2 = new MultipleChoice();
multipleChoiceQ2.addChoice("xyz");

list.add(multipleChoiceQ1);
list.add(multipleChoiceQ2);
```

Using this method, you can add other Objects to the list that are subclasses of `Question`like so:

```
TrueAndFalse trueAndFalse1 = new TrueAndFalse();
//do something here

TrueAndFalse trueAndFalse2 = new TrueAndFalse();
//do something here

list.add(trueAndFalse1);
list.add(trueAndFalse2);
```

Then when accessing the list use `instanceof` to check for the data type.
For example:

```
for (Question question : list) {
    if (question instanceof MultipleChoice) {
        MultipleChoice multipleChoice = (MultipleChoice) question;
        multipleChoice.doSomething();

    } else if (question instanceof TrueAndFalse) {
        TrueAndFalse trueAndFalse = (TrueAndFalse) question;
        trueAndFalse.doSomethingElse();

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't think `list.add(multipleChoiceQ1)` would work where `multipleChoiceQ1` is of type `MultipleChoice`. I don't know why I didn't try it that way. Now that I see it, it does seem intuitive. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your second solution.  Assuming the use of Java 1.5 or above, I would use generics.  For example:

```
public abstract class Question<T>
{
  public void addChoice(T newChoice);
}

public class MultipleChoice extends Question<String>
{
  @Override
  public void addChoice(String newChoice)
  {
    // Do whatever you want here
  }
}
```

You could use `Boolean` for True/False questions.

As Keale suggested, you could also just add all the choices to the Question **before** you add the Question to the list.  Have you considered perhaps using a constructor where you supply all the items up front?

Typecasting in the way you suggest for your first solution could eventually result in runtime errors if you attempt to cast something incorrectly.  Say you have the following list of Question objects, by type:

```
MultipleChoice
MultipleChoice
Boolean
MultipleChoice
Question
```

When you loop over this list, you only know you have a list of Question objects.  You have to check the type of each question before attempting to cast (using instanceof), or somehow keep track of which item in the list is of which type.  Have a think about what will happen if you try to execute `(MultipleChoice)list.get(2)`.

Comment: Good answer. Your answer is valid too. Goes to show how people think differently. :) IMHO however the addChoice method is only for the MultipleChoice. Other Question subclasses might have different answer types. This is difficult to decide without seeing the Question superclass and what it does exactly.

Comment: @Keale - yes, I thought of that.  The OP does not mention what the TrueFalse class does.  If it has an initialisation-style method broadly equivalent to addChoice, this could be genericised in Question.  If not, I agree with your response that it would be unwise to create such a method in Question if it only applies to MultipleChoice.  Bottom line, anything relevant to all questions should be in Question - whether or not child classes need to override depends on the child class' required behaviour.